# reminder as part of app in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on a project on android studio, it about medication reminder and I have some difficulties that how can I import a reminder in it.
for example I want the user to set the time as when he want to take his pill and then alert him at that time.
So, I search a lot but I did not find a suitable thing.
the reminder is part of my app so I want it as simple as possible.
I hope you understand me.

I tried this code but it didn't work !

```
            final Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
            final int hours = calender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            final int minutes = calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            alarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TimePickerDialog pickTime = new TimePickerDialog(AddMedication.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                            alarm.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                        }
                    }, hours, minutes, true);
                }
            });
```

Comment: You can use `AlarmManager` for that which is provided in Android SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method you show in your post is suitable when the app is running in the foreground all the time which is usually not the case.

The solution you need is using AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver to accomplish this:

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr;
PendingIntent alarmIntent;

alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
        60 * 1000, alarmIntent); //this alarm for example is set for the next minute
```

in your `AlarmReceiver` class you will have `onReceive` method:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //Either start an activity or send a notification here
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but where I put the first code ? in which function? onCreate?

Comment: @NujudAli anywhere you feel you want to setup the alarm